# Using HTTPResponse to return prettified dictionary

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to return a `HTTPResponse` object that is prettified JSON. I know that the `indent` parameter for `json` only works when you're printing. And printing converts an argument to a string. So shouldn't the `indent` parameter work if I just `str()` on my JSON before returning it?

```
def conversationview(request, convo_identification):
    data = InputInfo.objects.all()
    conversation_identification = convo_identification
    #conversation_id = {'conversation_id': []}
    header = {'conversation_id': '', 'messages': []}
    entry = {}
    output = {}

    for i in data:
        if str(i.conversation_id) == conversation_identification:
            header['conversation_id'] = i.conversation_id
            entry = {}
            entry['sender'] = i.name
            entry['message_body'] = i.message_body
            entry['date_created'] = str(i.created)
            header.get('messages').append(entry)
            #parsed = json.loads(header)
            convert_to_json = json.dumps(header, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
            output = str(convert_to_json)

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Can you add the error which you are getting.

Comment: I don't feel there is a need to prettify the json response before sending it.

Comment: There's no error returning, the dictionary is displaying just not with the indents

Comment: Are you saying I should prettify it after or not at all?

Comment: I assumed that you were getting error while prettifying.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Im using python 2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165387/discussion-between-v-coder-and-amon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing content-type parameter in your `HttpResponse` return statement

```
return HttpResponse(convert_to_json,content-type='application/json')
```

or if you want to pass it in template pass it in `<pre>` tag it wil preserve the indentation